# How to print from Visual Studio Object Browser

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on mapping two objects in .NET.

I would like to be able to print the items in the properties list from the Object Browser window in Visual Studio 2008.  Is there a way to print that information out to the console?

If that is not possible, what is a good method to print a general definition of a class (property names, method names)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the property list from the Object Browser you will probably need to write a VS add-in.
For the second question: you can use `System.Reflection` to get all the properties and methods, and work from there.

Answer (score 2):

You could just take a screenshot of the Object Browser and print it. Simple but effective.